# Is there typological symbolism between Jesus rising on the first day (Matt. 28:1) and God creating light on the first day (Gen. 1:3)?

Tags: genesis, gospels, typology

Is there symbolism between Jesus rising on the first day (Matt. 28:1) and God creating light on the first day (Gen. 1:3)?  The seventh day, the Sabbath, was when God rested.  Christians changed the day of worship to Sunday, the first day, when Jesus rose from the dead.  Does this have a typological significance to God creating light on the first day?  An example of typology is Jesus was born in Bethlehem. Bethlehem means house of bread. Jesus is the bread of life.  It is an affirmation of theology that already exists rather than a basis for theology.

Comment: I am struggling to see any connection (apart from a possible homiletic one) between these two verses.  Specifically, they only have a single word in common, "first".  In Gen 1:5 has "yom echad" (first day) and Matt 28:1 has "mian sabbaton" (first of the week).  At a stretch one might say "dawn" in Matt 28:1 has a root word meaning "light" similar to that in Gen 1:3 but this verse lacks "first".  However, Jesus claimed to be the light of the world (John 8:12) but what day that was we are not told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one is looking for a connection between Jesus and Gen 1, the best is found in John 1:1-5 with Gen 1:1-3

- Both have "in the beginning"
- Both discuss the creation of things
- John 1:1 has the "Word" and Gen 1:3 has "God said"
- Both discuss light and darkness

Later chapters of John enlarge on this by recording Jesus famous statement that:

> "I am the light of the world" (John 8:12)

Several of Jesus' "I am" claims were linked to "life" that was first created in that first creation week:

- “I am” the Bread of **Life** (John 6:35-51)
- “I am” the Resurrection & **Life** (John 11:25)
- “I am” the Way, Truth & **Life** (John 14:6)
- “I am” the Vine (John 15:1-5), ie, the source of spiritual (and eternal, 1 John 5:11, 12) life for all Christians

Other than this, I cannot see a direct connection to Matt 28:1, other than (interpretatively as distinct from linguistically) the dawn being the first light of the day, but that is a stretch.

Comment: @Dottard you are very close to a good answer.  What if you include v5? 4 In him was life, and the life was the light of men. 5 The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.  
(John 1:4–5, ESV) especially considering their proximity.  Basically, you answer it.

Comment: Basically, the connection is like, Jesus was born in Bethlehem.  Bethlehem means *house of bread*.  Jesus is the bread of life.  The connection is implicit as a typology.

Comment: We run into a problem if we try to make the connection stronger than a simple typology.  Typology is not what we base theology on.

Comment: @PerryWebb - my apologies - I intended the John reference to include V5 because it contains the reference to light and darkness and the light of life.  I will update the reference.  I agree with your remark.

Comment: Does the edit to my question make it clearer?

Comment: @PerryWebb - that is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The first אוֹר "Or" (Light) of [Genesis 1:3, Day-1] was Not "the-great-luminary" הַמָּא֤וֹר הַגָּדֹל֙ of [Genesis 1:16, Day-4] known as "shemesh שֶׁ֚מֶשׁ" (the sun).

The risen "Sun" of the Christian Sabbath (Sunday) was proclaimed in March 7, 321 by Emporer Constantine who believed Jesus of Nazareth = Sol (Sun) deity : "All judges and city people and the craftsmen shall rest upon the venerable day of - the sun."

**If Jesus is "the sun" (sol invictus) to Constantine, then he was made on day-4 of creation & cannot be the first Light of Genesis.**

Comment: Good answer. +1.

Comment: I gave you a +1.  Constantine was using symbolism much stronger than typology.  There is a problem with identifying Christ directly to a part of creation when John 1 identifies the Word as the creator.

Comment: Actually, the Christian Sabbath was celebrated by Christians long before the days Of Constantine. For example, Justin "The Martyr", a Christian and philosopher that lived in the 2nd century (approx. between the year 100 and the year 160) said in his writings: "On (the first day) we all gather together, because this is the day when God, at the creation of the world, separated the light from the darkness and on which our Savior Jesus Christ rose from the dead."

Comment: Another example is in the Epistle the Magnesians, written by Ignatius Theophorus of Antioch (approx. between the year  40 and the year 110): "Those, then, who lived by ancient practices arrived at a new hope. They ceased to keep the Sabbath and lived by the Lord’s Day (the first day), on which our life as well as theirs shone forth, thanks to Him and his death, though some deny this."